# VSCode Inside Curly Braces indentation

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a setting in VSCode in handles the indents of any content inside curly braces. I currently have my tab size set to 4. But for some reason everything inside a curly brace in javascript only has about a 2 on spacing.

Something like this:

```
 copy(tableType) {
   this.selectElementContents(document.getElementById(tableType));
},
```

When in reality I want something like this:

```
 copy(tableType) {
     this.selectElementContents(document.getElementById(tableType));
},
```

Basically a more noticeable indent so anything inside curly braces. Anyone knows of a setting that handles this?

Comment: are you using a formatting extension? if so, try to look up its settings in the settings UI

Comment: There are many such settings... and available on a per language overrides as well. As Tedskovsky notes language tools often add far more detailed control. (Eg. [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) for working with Vue.js uses one of [several plugins](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/formatting.html).)